# React Redux - Normalizr - Selecting from nested data - select by id

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

So kind of stuck on this problem. I've gotten a response for a list of artwork, which is a deeply nested response. I have normalized this response using the normalizr library.

You can check out the Schema below:

../schema.js

```
import { Schema, arrayOf } from 'normalizr'

const artboardSchema = new Schema('artboards', { idAttribute: 'id' });
const artistSchema = new Schema('artists', { idAttribute: 'id' });
const lastArtSchema = new Schema('lastArt', { idAttribute: 'id' });
const artSchema = new Schema('art', { idAttribute: 'id' });
const artAssetSet = new Schema('artAssetSet', { idAttribute: 'url'});

artboardSchema.define({
    collaborated_by: arrayOf(artistSchema),
    last_art: lastArtSchema,
    art: arrayOf(artSchema)
});

artSchema.define({
   artasset_set: arrayOf(artAssetSet),
    performed_by: artistSchema
});

lastArtSchema.define({
   performed_by: artistSchema
});

export { artboardSchema }
```

This is working great so far, the data is being normalized and I'm getting the following response saved in the state tree:

```
artboard:
    entities:
        artboards {}
        artists {}
        lastArt {}
        art {}
        artAssetSet {}
    result:
        [2,3,4,5,6]
```

So now I have a component that gets this data and displays it.

../ArtCard.jsx

```
const ArtCard = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.cardContainer}>
            {props.item.result.map( id =>
                <div className={props.itemClass} value={id} key={id}>
                    <h5>{props.item.entities.artboards[id].name}</h5>

                    <p>{props.item.entities.artboards[id].uid}</p>

                    {props.item.entities.artboards[id].collaborated_by.map( id =>
                    <Avatar key={id} name={props.item.entities.artists[id].name} size={40} round={true}/>
                    )}
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => {
                        props.onSubmit()
                    }
                    }>Details</button>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

The above component gets the entire artboard object from the state tree, and then we run .map on it, to get the artboards by id.

The trouble I'm having is with regards to last_art, I want to display the artist that did the last art, I'm able to get the id by placing `{props.item.entities.artboards[id].last_art}`, but I'm having trouble using this to get the info from lastArt, i.e. this would be something like `{props.item.entities.lastArt[id].date}` or `{props.item.entities.lastArt[id].artist}` as last_art is not an array, but just a `Number`, meaning I can't use `map` on it.

Is there a better way to do this? What am I missing in this case?

Comment: May be can't get into your question properly! What actually your `lastArt` contains ?

Comment: `lastArt` has a date and `artist` in it.

Comment: then call it as `props.item.entities.lastArt.date` or `props.item.entities.lastArt.artist` since it has no dependency with `id` or `artist`

Comment: No, we need the `id` which is gotten from `{props.item.entities.artboards[id].last_art}` and then we can get them by `props.item.entities.lastArt[id].date`

Comment: The state has been normalized, as you can see from the above entities structure.

Comment: Just to clarify, `artboards` has an attribute `last_art`, which just stores the id, through which we can get `lastArt`

Comment: can you log the `artboard` and append this to your post?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127436/discussion-between-jyothi-babu-araja-and-md85).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this, it was actually a fairly simple solution. I had to account for the last_art id being null as well.

```
const PatientCard = (props) => {
        return (
            <div className={props.cardContainer}>
                {props.item.result.map( id =>
                    <div className={props.itemClass} value={id} key={id}>
                        <h5>{props.item.entities.artboards[id].name}</h5>

                        <span className={props.lastArtClass}>
                            {props.item.entities.artboards[id].last_art !== null &&
                            <span>
                                <span>{props.item.entities.artists[props.item.entities.lastArt[props.item.entities.artboards[id].last_art].performed_by].name}, </span>
                                <FormattedRelative value={props.item.entities.lastArt[props.item.entities.artboards[id].last_art].date} />
                            </span>
                            }
                            {props.item.entities.artboards[id].last_art === null &&
                            <p>N/A</p>
                            }
                        </span>

                        {props.item.entities.artboards[id].collaborated_by.map( id =>
                            <Avatar key={id} name={props.item.entities.artists[id].name} size={40} round={true}/>
                        )}
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => {
                            props.onSubmit()
                        }
                        }>Details</button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    };
```

I think there is definitely a better way to do this using Reselect.